# failing to change a divs text content with html5 data attributes

Tags: jquery, translate

So I implemented a way to translate my web content with a button click withouttrying to reload the page using html data-* attributes, in this case I use a the custom data attribute data-en to store the content of the div translated to english.

For some reason I can't see my little code doesn't hange the container's text content.

```js
<script>
$('.settingswheel').click(function() {
var e = $('.settingsin');
var en = e.dataset.en;
alert(en);
e.text(en);

});
</script>
```

```css
.postit {
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:hidden;
  left:1070px; 
  top:-155px; 
  padding-left:10px;
  line-height: 1;   
  width: 275px;    
  margin: 0px;    
  min-height:250px;
  max-height:250px;
  padding-top:35px; 
  border:1px solid #E8E8E8;  
  border-top:60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family:'Reenie Beanie';    
  font-size:22px;      
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display:inline-block;    
  background: #ffff88; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%,#ffff88), color-stop(82%,#ffff88), color-stop(82%,#ffff88), color-stop(100%,#ffffc6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%,#ffff88 82%,#ffff88 82%,#ffffc6 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffffc6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
 
.postit:after {     
  content: "";
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:-1;
  right:-0px; bottom:20px;
  width:200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow:2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.settingswheel{
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:22px; 
 right:15px; 
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:10001;
 -moz-transition: transform 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2.5s;
    transition: transform 2.5s;
}

.settingswheel:hover{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.settingsin{z-index:2; font-size:60px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:15px; background-color:rgb(255, 255, 136); position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:5px; transition: all 1.5s ease;}
.settingsout{z-index:2; font-size:60px; font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:15px; background-color:rgb(255, 255, 136); position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:-190px; transition: all 1.5s ease;}

.menu{
 list-style:none; 
 bottom:8px; 
 position:absolute; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 font-weight:300; 
 width:200px;
 z-index:1;
}

.menu ul li{font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;}

.suma{cursor:pointer;}
.resta{cursor:pointer;}
#languagetoggler{cursor:pointer;}
#fullscreentoggler{cursor:pointer;}
.flag{cursor:pointer;}
.amsheart{cursor:pointer;}
.amsterdam span{font-size:30px; font-weight:300;}
```

```html
<div class="postit">
  <img class="settingswheel" src="images/settings.png">
  <span class="settingsin" data-en="Settings">Ajustes</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li data-en="Full screen">Pantalla completa:  <span id="fullscreentoggler" value="F" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" data-en="yes">si</span></li>
 <li data-en="Language">Idioma:  <span id="languagetoggler" onclick="toggleLanguage()" >español</span></li>
 <li data-en="Slides">Diapositivas:  <span class="resta">< </span><span class="segundos">5s</span><span class="suma"> ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` is a jQuery object. A jQuery object doesn't have a `dataset` property

Use either

```
var en = e[0].dataset.en;
```

Or jQuery `data()` method

```
var en = e.data('en);
```

```js
$('.settingswheel').click(function() {
  var e = $('.settingsin');
  var en = e[0].dataset.en;
  // or
  //var en = e.data('en);
  alert(en);
  e.text(en);

});
```

```css
.postit {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1070px;
  top: -155px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  border-top: 60px solid #fdfd86;
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie';
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffff88;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(81%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(82%, #ffff88), color-stop(100%, #ffffc6));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffff88 81%, #ffff88 82%, #ffff88 82%, #ffffc6 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff88', endColorstr='#ffffc6', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.postit:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -0px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  -moz-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform: matrix(-1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.settingswheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10001;
  -moz-transition: transform 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2.5s;
  transition: transform 2.5s;
}

.settingswheel:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.settingsin {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.settingsout {
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 136);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: -190px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.suma {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resta {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#languagetoggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#fullscreentoggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flag {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.amsheart {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.amsterdam span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="postit">
  <i class="fa fa-bars settingswheel"></i>
  <span class="settingsin" data-en="Settings">Ajustes</span>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li data-en="Full screen">Pantalla completa: <span id="fullscreentoggler" value="F" onclick="toggleFullScreen()" data-en="yes">si</span></li>
    <li data-en="Language">Idioma: <span id="languagetoggler" onclick="toggleLanguage()">español</span></li>
    <li data-en="Slides">Diapositivas: <span class="resta">&gt; </span><span class="segundos">5s</span><span class="suma"> ></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is `erroneous` no output missing `'` in `var en = e.data('en);`

Answer (score 0):

e is a jquery object, you can access data attributes with the data function.

```
var en = e.data('en');
```

prints "Settings"